# How to encrypt using AES with sha256 hash as key crypto++

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, crypto++

I have a string hashed using SHA256 to use as a key but how would I use this key to encrypt a string with AES in CBC mode and crypto++?
Thanks.

Comment: You probably should read up on crypto basics. _How_ you created your key doesn't matter. The SHA256 is a red herring.

Comment: @MSalters Ok thanks, I have a basic understanding of how AES in CBC mode works but I was just explaining how I had made the key but I understand how that doesn't matter.

Comment: Why would you hash a string you wanted to use as a key? Why not use a proper key derivation scheme?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It's not _that_ bad as a key derivation scheme. An SHA256 hash has the desirable property that no bit of the hash relates in a trivial way on any bit of the input.

Comment: Due to my limited knowledge about key derivation schemes I chose to use a hashing method as I have previously used this and I am still learning about encryption. I know that using a hash is not as secure as a proper KDF but the main aim of my question was to ask how to use the crypto++ library with a key of known 32 bytes, I should have made this clear in the question.

Comment: I expect that you already found this, but just to be sure: [The documentation for CBC encryption](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CBC_Mode) may be of some help. It includes an [example](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CBC_Mode#Sample_Program) encryption program.

Comment: I have found this already and seen the example program but I am new to using the Crypto++ library and I am not sure how I would use a known key instead of the randomly generated one in the example.

Comment: *"Due to my limited knowledge about key derivation schemes ... "* - Use [HKDF](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HKDF). Also see [Crypto++ hkdf](https://www.google.com/search?q=crypto%2B%2B). There's lots of examples on the Crypto++ wiki. You should also visit [Authenticated Encryption](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) when it comes time to select a mode of operation.

Comment: @jww ok thanks I will have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up achieving the desired outcome with the below code.

```
    QString qhash = "hash";
    std::string plain = "message";
    std::string ciphertext;
    std::string stdhash = qhash.toStdString();

    CryptoPP::HexDecoder decoder;
    decoder.Put((byte*)stdhash.data(),qhash.size());
    decoder.MessageEnd();

    CryptoPP::word64 size = decoder.MaxRetrievable();
    char *decodedKey = new char[size];
    decoder.Get((byte *)decodedKey, size);

    byte hash[CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH], iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];

    CryptoPP::StringSource(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(decodedKey), true,new CryptoPP::ArraySink(hash, CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH));
    memset(iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption Encryptor(hash,sizeof(hash),iv);
    CryptoPP::StringSource( plain, true, new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter( Encryptor, new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext )) ) );
    return ciphertext;
```

Comment: Why didn't you use Qt for everything? It seems like mixing things would complicate tasks for you.

Comment: That code does not look very healthy to me. You did not use a key derivation function. One of the [Pipelines](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining) does nothing.

Comment: @jww I didn't use Qt for everything because I wanted the code to be used in a different project as well that did not use Qt. I didn't use a KDF because I am not sure how to properly implement a KDF with authenticated encryption but I am currently researching how to do this. This function solved my original goal and that is why I posted it as an answer.